# JasperReports: move elements after subreport

Tags: jasper-reports

My current parent report:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="mainTemplate" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="774" leftMargin="25" rightMargin="43" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="43" uuid="f6278978-d9b2-42df-8b72-6557197bf6bf">
    <style name="footer" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Verdana" fontSize="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="fonts/verdanabd.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    <parameter name="objectCode" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="objectDescrition" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="pages" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="pageNumberTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="2" y="2" width="771" height="25" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="664a8b98-1aef-491f-82b0-4a6ffea7081f"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="footer" x="16" y="2" width="491" height="25" uuid="56521af5-f104-4bbd-b6ab-fd7b6b502dca"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<span style='font-weight: bold;'></span>" + $P{objectDescrition}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="771" height="15" uuid="87b6f002-8f10-4b20-9e3f-b6d2bb73037a"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($P{pages})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "exportCommentsWithMarks.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="exportCommentsWithMarks" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="774" leftMargin="25" rightMargin="43" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="43" uuid="b5753b46-4511-49e4-8a4c-faebef13bd0b">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="comments" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="media" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="392" y="0" width="379" height="71" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="adf5d1b5-9361-4d5e-9ee7-4d1bde126198"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource($F{comments})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "marksReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <image isUsingCache="true" isLazy="true">
                <reportElement x="28" y="35" width="351" height="365" uuid="6ebaced5-b797-404c-a893-8fa689f8e09d"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{media}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Current result is, a rectangle and textField on one page of a report:
[image: First page with a rectangle and textField]

And the subreport is on the next page of report:
 [image: 2nd page with subreport]

I want a subreport is placed immediately after a rectangle and textField of main report, without page break.

Comment: have you tried splitType="Immediate"

Comment: @PetterFriberg, I tried to set it to a band of a parent template, but with no access. I got the same result.

Comment: set all splitType="Immediate" and check that height of your subreport  (including margins) may fit to a page with height=595-53(margins)-30(posistion of subreport)=512

Comment: @PetterFriberg, it helped! thank you very much!

Comment: I answered as community wiki (no rep) to close question, I you feel that the question is useful for other's accept it otherwise delete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set all `splitType="Immediate"` and check that height of your subreport (including margins) may fit to a page with height=595-53(margins)-30(position of subreport)=512